Mean Value Property of Complex Analytic Functions Using Harmonic Function MVT
The Mean Value Property for complex analytic functions and the Mean Value Theorem for harmonic functions (Real valued) look similar:
Mean Value Property for Harmonic  Functions:
For a harmonic function $h$ in a ball $B_r(x_0, y_0)$:
$$
h(x_0, y_0) = \frac{1}{2 \pi r} \int_{\partial B_r(x_0, y_0)} h(x, y) \, ds
$$
Mean Value Property for Complex Analytic Functions:
For a complex analytic function $f$ and a closed contour $\gamma$:
$$
f(z_0) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z - z_0} \, dz
$$
Since real and imaginary parts of complex analytic functins are harmonic, can we derive MVT for complex analytic functions using MVT for harmonic functions?
Thank you for your insights!

Is $\gamma$ a closed circle with center $z_0$, or an arbitrary closed curve?

I mean in a particular case of gramma being a circle with center z_0

I suggest that you add that information to your question.

If $\gamma$ is a circle with center $z_0 = x_0 + iy_0$ and radius $r > 0$ then we can parameterize it as $\gamma(t) = z_0 + r e^{it}$, $0 \le t \le 2 \pi$, and we get
$$
\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z - z_0} \, dz = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_0^{2 \pi} f(re^{it}) \, dt = \frac{1}{2 \pi r} \int_{\partial B_r(x_0, y_0)} f(x, y) \, ds \, .
$$
With $u = \operatorname{Re}(f)$ and  $v = \operatorname{Im}(f)$ this is equal to
$$
 \frac{1}{2 \pi r} \int_{\partial B_r(x_0, y_0)} u(x, y) \, ds
+ i \frac{1}{2 \pi r} \int_{\partial B_r(x_0, y_0)} v(x, y) \, ds
= u(x_0, y_0 ) + iv(x_0, y_0) = f(z_0) \, .
$$
So the mean-value property of holomorphic functions is an immediate consequence of the mean-value property of harmonic functions, applied to the real and the imaginary part of $f$ separately.
(It is assumed that $f$ is holomorphic in a neighborhood of the disk $B_r(z_0)$.)
Conversely, if $u$ is harmonic in a neighborhood of the disk $B_r(z_0)$ then $u =\operatorname{Re}(f)$ with some holomorphic function, so that the mean-value property of harmonic functions can also be derived from the mean-value property of holomorphic functions (which is a special case of Cauchy's integral formula).
